# How to make search for all phrases in the text and replace them with another phrase (IPv4 address search and validation)

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

How to make search for all phrases in the text and replace them with another phrase

```
(by using sed and/or awk and/or grep and/or perl) ?
```

It's about replacing one IPv4 address with another one and verify that the value found is the correct IPv4 address.

Here's an example:

```
ip_node:<ip_address> e.g. ip_node:192.168.0.1
```

These should be replaced by

```
ip_address:<ip_address>” e.g. "ip_address:192.168.0.1"
```

---

Additional assumptions:

```
-> Phrases such 
   192.168.000.001, 072.12.01.1, 256.224.1.010, 20.128.300.01
   and similar aren't propoer IPv4 addresses and should be marked as
   invalid IPv4 address and possibly write to another file.
-> Phrases containing less/more than 4 octets aren't also considered
   to be a valid IPv4 addresses and like above should be marked as
   invalid IPv4 address and possibly write to another file.
-> Phrases containing any character other than a digit [0..9] aren't also
   considered to be a valid IPv4 addresses and like above should be marked as
   invalid IPv4 address and possibly write to another file.
```

---

Content of sample file:

```
ip_node:192.168.0.1
ip_node:192.268.0.01
ip_node:10.0.0.0
ip_node:10.0.0000.10
ip_node:10.255.255.255
ip_node:10.255.255.255.12
ip_node:172.16.0.0
ip_node:172.16.0
ip_node:172.31.255.255
ip_node:172.31.255.
ip_node:0.0.0.0
ip_node:01.0.01.0
ip_node:255.255.255.255
ip_node:255.259.255.259
ip_node:224.0.0.0
ip_node:224.0.
ip_node:207.142.131.236
ip_node:207.002.001.06
ip_node:255.255.255.0
ip_node:055.2255.1255.0
ip_node:204.144.134.234
ip_node:2o7.0o2.0E.O6
ip_node:245.245.245.40
ip_node:O55.2255.1255.a0
```

Content of output file1-all (with all entries):

```
ip_address:192.168.0.1
[!]ip_node:192.268.0.01  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:10.0.0.0
[!]ip_node:10.0.0000.10  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:10.255.255.255
[!]ip_node:10.255.255.255.12  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:172.16.0.0
[!]ip_node:172.16.0  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:172.31.255.255
[!]ip_node:172.31.255.  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:0.0.0.0
[!]ip_node:01.0.01.0  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:255.255.255.255
[!]ip_node:255.259.255.259  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:224.0.0.0
[!]ip_node:224.0.  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:207.142.131.236
[!]ip_node:207.002.001.06  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:255.255.255.0
[!]ip_node:055.2255.1255.0  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:204.144.134.234
[!]ip_node:2o7.0o2.0E.O6  -- [invalid IP address]
ip_address:245.245.245.40
[!]ip_node:O55.2255.1255.a0  -- [invalid IP address]
```

Content of output file2-bad (only with bad entries):

```
[!]ip_node:192.268.0.01  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:10.0.0000.10  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:10.255.255.255.12  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:172.16.0  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:172.31.255.  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:01.0.01.0  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:255.259.255.259  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:224.0.  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:207.002.001.06  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:055.2255.1255.0  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:2o7.0o2.0E.O6  -- [invalid IP address]
[!]ip_node:O55.2255.1255.a0  -- [invalid IP address]
```

Content of output file3-good (only with valid entries):

```
ip_address:192.168.0.1
ip_address:10.0.0.0
ip_address:10.255.255.255
ip_address:172.16.0.0
ip_address:172.31.255.255
ip_address:0.0.0.0
ip_address:255.255.255.255
ip_address:224.0.0.0
ip_address:207.142.131.236
ip_address:255.255.255.0
ip_address:204.144.134.234
ip_address:245.245.245.40
```

Attempts:

```
sed -i -e "s/ip_node:/ip_address:/g" <file>
```

and this:

```
sed -i -e "s/ip_node:^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][‌​0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/ip_address:^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0‌​-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/g" <file>
```

Comment: Surely you've tried something before seeking help, right?

Comment: Yep. Something like this: sed -i -e "s/ip_node:/ip_address:/g" <file> and this: sed -i -e "s/ip_node:^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/ip_address:^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/g" <file> but it's only garbage and that's why I don't mentioned it...

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with "01.0.01.0" or "207.002.001.06"? Why do you think they are invalid?

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -nle '
    if (/ip_node:\K(\S+)/ && $1 =~ /^($RE{net}{IPv4})$/) {
        print "ip_address", $1;
    } else {
        print "[!]", $_;
    }
' filename
```

outputs

```
ip_address192.168.0.1
[!]ip_node:192.268.0.01
ip_address10.0.0.0
[!]ip_node:10.0.0000.10
ip_address10.255.255.255
[!]ip_node:10.255.255.255.12
ip_address172.16.0.0
[!]ip_node:172.16.0
ip_address172.31.255.255
[!]ip_node:172.31.255.
ip_address0.0.0.0
ip_address01.0.01.0
ip_address255.255.255.255
[!]ip_node:255.259.255.259
ip_address224.0.0.0
[!]ip_node:224.0.
ip_address207.142.131.236
ip_address207.002.001.06
ip_address255.255.255.0
[!]ip_node:055.2255.1255.0
ip_address204.144.134.234
[!]ip_node:2o7.0o2.0E.O6
ip_address245.245.245.40
[!]ip_node:O55.2255.1255.a0
```

For splitting it into your desired output files, I would:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -nle '... as above ...' filename |
tee file1-all |
awk '/^\[!\]/ {print > "file2-bad"; next} {print > "file3-good"}'
```

Comment: 01.0.01.0 or 207.002.001.06 aren't invalid at all. I just wanted to delete all leading zeros. BTW. 2130706433 and 127.1 are valid too. Try to ping them... BTW2. Some code explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution:

```
awk -f check.awk input.txt
```

where `check.awk` is

```
{
    split($0,a,":")  #splits line at ":"
    ip=a[2]          #part after ":"
    if (validIP(ip))
        printf "ip_address:%s%s", ip, ORS  
    else 
        printf "[!]%s%s%s",$0," -- [invalid IP address]", ORS

}

function validIP(ip, a, n, i) { #last three parameters are local variables
    n=split(ip,a,".")           #splits ip in 4 octets
    if (n==4) {
        for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
            if (!(match(a[i],/^[0-9]+$/))) return (0)  #must be digits
            if (match(a[i],/^0[0-9]+/)) return (0)     #no leading zeros
            if (a[i]>255) return (0)
        }
        return (1)
    }
    else return(0)
}
```

Comment: Please, explain these parts of code:  `split($0,a,":")`  `ip=a[2]`  `function validIP(ip, a, n, i)`  `{ n=split(ip,a,".")`  `ORS, %s`

Comment: See comments in code.. ORS is the output record separator, its default value is the newline character "\n"

Comment: I think you can hold down the SHIFT key while pressing <enter>.. The %s is a placeholder for the arguments, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: $0 is contents of the input line in `awk`

Comment: The %s is substitued for by the arguments. If there is only one argument, we use a single %s; if you look at the line with three %s, you can see that there are three arguments..